# Mule MEL, how to get a property value?

Tags: mule

In the Mule MEL, how to get a property value ?

In the java code, I did this:

```
eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("amount", 100);
```

I have tried these options

```
#[message.invocationProperty.invocation]
#[message.invocationProperty('invocation')]
#[message.getInvocationProperty().get('invocation')]
```

I realize that message is an instance of org.mule.el.context.MessageContext, then what is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `#[message.inboundProperties['propertyName']]` or `#[message.invocationProperties['propertyName']]`

Comment: your solution works. please see my update first. In the flow I set variable value like this, <set-variable variableName="amount" value="message.invocationProperties['amount']" /> . This time I got this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String . do you have any solution ?

Comment: I do not have `.invocationProperties` binds to message property variable. I am using mule 5.1.2 anypoint studio and java 1.8V. It throws exception when I try message.invocationProperties

Comment: Try using Anypoint Studio 5.2.0, I don't know why it doesn't work for you , but using the latest version perhaps can solve your problem.

Comment: Works to get variables from INVOCATION OR INBOUND scopes. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you set a variable with scope INVOCATION (with Message Enricher or Variable), you can get the variable with the syntax below:

`#flowVars['your_Variable_Name']`

Comment: Don't forget the `#`. For all the noobs like me, this is the full expression that worked for me: `#[flowVars.your_Variable_Name]`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the sintaxis is almost the same, it depends on the scope of the property variable, but the most usual way is:

`#[flowVars['flow_var_name']]`

In my personal opinion **I don't recommend to use:**

`#[flowVars.variable]`

Because in some complex environment with many messageContext switches the variable could get lost. I recommend to take a look on the next [post from Mulesoft oficial blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/) that shows how to handle Properties and variables.

Answer (score 0):

This answer for your comment

```
<set-variable variableName="amount" value="message.invocationProperties['amount']" />
```

Solution is

```
<set-variable variableName="amount" value="#[message.invocationProperties['amount']]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Invocation properties of a message follow this syntax:

`#[flowVars.parameter]` or `#[flowVars['paramater']]`